# How to count a frequency of a particular word in a line?

Tags: java, string

I would like to know, that if I am having a single line string, then how to count the frequency of a particular word in that string, using simple java code?!

Thanks in advance..

---

What I am looking for is a sample logical code in java which is used to search a particular word in a sentence. I am building one spam filter, which needs to read the line and then classify it.

Answer (score 10):

[`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has:

```
StringUtils.countMatches(string, searchedFor);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression. An example of code is:

```
public int count(String word, String line){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    int counter = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
        counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First split by spaces (see [String#split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29))

Then use a map to map the words with frequency.

```
String [] words = line.split(" ");

Map<String,Integer> frequency = new Map <String,Integer>();

for (String word:words){

    Integer f = frequency.get(word);
    frequency.put(word,f+1);
}
```

Then you can find out for a particular word with:

```
frequency.get(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:**

1. **[MultiSet](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)**(*Use when count of all words are required*)

   ```
   String line="Hello world bye bye world";
   Multiset<String> countStr=HashMultiset.create(Splitter.on(' ').split(line)); 
   System.out.println(countStr.count("Hello")); //gives count of the word 'Hello'
   ```
2. **[Iterators](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html)**(*Use when count of only few words are required*)

   ```
   String line="Hello world bye bye world";
   Iterable<String> splitStr=Splitter.on(' ').split(line);
   System.out.println(Iterables.frequency(splitStr, "Hello"));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

After Googleing and little study i got this stuff __ may be helpfull

```
String str="hello new demo hello";
Map<String,Integer> hmap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(String tempStr : str.split(" "))
{
  if(hmap.containsKey(tempStr))
  {
     Integer i=hmap.get(tempStr);
     i+=1;
     hmap.put(tempStr,i);
  }
  else
     hmap.put(tempStr,1);
}
System.out.println(hmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways:

1. Use splits
2. Use tokenizers
3. Use Regular Expressions
4. Use good old loops and string manipulation (ie indexOf(), etc)

Option 1 & 2 has the overhead of trying to figure out if your word happens to be the last on the line (and needing to add an additional count)

Option 3 requires you to be able to form regex syntax

Option 4 is archaic

Answer (score 0):

After getting the string array you can try the following code from Java 10 onwards. It uses streams to get the frequency map.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StringFrequencyMap {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] wordArray = {"One", "two", "three", "one", "two", "two", "three"};
        var freqCaseSensitive = Arrays.stream(wordArray)
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
        //If you want case insensitive then use
        var freqCaseInSensitive = Arrays.stream(wordArray)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(freqCaseSensitive);
        System.out.println(freqCaseInSensitive);
        System.out.println("Frequency of \"two\" is: "+freqCaseInSensitive.get("two"));
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
{one=1, One=1, three=2, two=3}
{one=2, three=2, two=3}
Frequency of "two" is: 3
```